# ChannelListners infinitly growing

Tags: jxbrowser

In my JxBrowser Application I create and dispose a browser for each request based on given needs. After several hundred requests, I begin to received a "Failed to get Browser browserChannel" exception. In an attempt to debug this, I noticed that I have an ever growing number of ChannelListeners. I added the following code to my application after the browser.dispose() to see this.

```
    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(IPC.getDefault().getMainChannel().getChannelListeners())) {
        List<ChannelListener> channelListeners = IPC.getDefault().getMainChannel().getChannelListeners();
        for(ChannelListener listener : channelListeners) {
            logger.info("Listener: " + listener.getClass());
        }
    }
```

I see these 4 repeat in my logs as a result

```
    2018-06-21 13:30:28,105 [pool-3-thread-1] INFO  c.t.l.l.a.service.BrowserManager - Listener: class com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.ZoomService$a 
    2018-06-21 13:30:28,105 [pool-3-thread-1] INFO  c.t.l.l.a.service.BrowserManager - Listener: class com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.NetworkService$a 
    2018-06-21 13:30:28,105 [pool-3-thread-1] INFO  c.t.l.l.a.service.BrowserManager - Listner: class com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.NotificationService$a 
    2018-06-21 13:30:28,105 [pool-3-thread-1] INFO  c.t.l.l.a.service.BrowserManager - Listener: class com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.ProtocolService$a
```

Is this there something I'm not disposing correctly? Is this a JxBrowser issue, maybe related to my IPCException?

Answer (score 0):

These 4 listeners belong to the default `IPC` instance that is implemented as a singleton. So, once you access the default `IPC` instance through the `IPC.getDefault()`, these 4 listeners are registered and we never unregister them.

FYI: the library might create a lot of `ChannelListeners` inside. These listeners are part of the internal private logic. They are removed when it's necessary.

As for the "Failed to get Browser browserChannel" error message – this error message indicates that the library failed to initialize the `Browser` instance. In this case the log messages should be analyzed to detect the root cause of the issue.